# "No Such File or Directory" Though the File is There?

Tags: php, apache

I am getting this error message:

```
    Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/1f77f7e78f36847859c0604e9645f112.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ubergallery\multiple_image_upload\upload.php on line 17

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpE035.tmp' to 'uploads/1f77f7e78f36847859c0604e9645f112.jpg' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ubergallery\multiple_image_upload\upload.php on line 17
1).please try again!.
```

"upload.php" is included inside "multiupload.php" and I am looking to include "multiupload.php" inside "index.php" which is located here:

```
ubergallery/resources/themes/uber-blue/index.php
```

The other two files are located here:

```
ubergallery/multiple_image_upload/multiupload.php
ubergallery/multiple_image_upload/upload.php
```

This is upload.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $j = 0; //Variable for indexing uploaded image 

    $target_path = "uploads/"; //Declaring Path for uploaded images
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {//loop to get individual element from the array

        $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");  //Extensions which are allowed
        $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));//explode file name from dot(.) 
        $file_extension = end($ext); //store extensions in the variable

        $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];//set the target path with a new name of image
        $j = $j + 1;//increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array       

      if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 100000) //Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
                && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {//if file moved to uploads folder
                echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
            } else {//if file was not moved.
                echo $j. ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
            }
        } else {//if file size and file type was incorrect.
            echo $j. ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And this is index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Qinter</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo THEMEPATH; ?>/images/favicon.png" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo THEMEPATH; ?>/rebase-min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo THEMEPATH; ?>/style.css" />
    <?php echo $gallery->getColorboxStyles(5); ?>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <?php echo $gallery->getColorboxScripts(); ?>

    <?php file_exists('googleAnalytics.inc') ? include('googleAnalytics.inc') : false; ?>



    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/ubergallery/multiple_image_upload/script.js"></script>

    <!-------Including CSS File------>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/ubergallery/multiple_image_upload/style.css">




</head>
<body>
<div class="imageupload clearfix">
    <?php
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/ubergallery/multiple_image_upload/multiupload.php');

    ?>

    </div>


<!-- Start UberGallery v<?php echo UberGallery::VERSION; ?> - Copyright (c) <?php echo date('Y'); ?> Chris Kankiewicz (http://www.ChrisKankiewicz.com) -->
<div id="galleryWrapper">
    <div class="line"></div>

    <?php if($gallery->getSystemMessages()): ?>
        <ul id="systemMessages">
            <?php foreach($gallery->getSystemMessages() as $message): ?>
                <li class="<?php echo $message['type']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $message['text']; ?>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>


    <div id="galleryListWrapper">
        <?php if (!empty($galleryArray) && $galleryArray['stats']['total_images'] > 0): ?>
            <ul id="galleryList" class="clearfix">
                <?php foreach ($galleryArray['images'] as $image): ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo html_entity_decode($image['file_path']); ?>" title="<?php echo $image['file_title']; ?>" rel="colorbox"><img src="<?php echo $image['thumb_path']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['file_title']; ?>"/></a></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <div class="line"></div>
    <div id="galleryFooter" class="clearfix">

        <?php if ($galleryArray['stats']['total_pages'] > 1): ?>
        <ul id="galleryPagination">

            <?php foreach ($galleryArray['paginator'] as $item): ?>

                <li class="<?php echo $item['class']; ?>">
                    <?php if (!empty($item['href'])): ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $item['href']; ?>"><?php echo $item['text']; ?></a>
                    <?php else: ?><?php echo $item['text']; ?><?php endif; ?>
                </li>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>


    </div>
</div>
<!-- End UberGallery - Distributed under the MIT license: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php -->

</body>
</html>
```

I hope you can help with the error message.

```
No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ubergallery\multiple_image_upload\upload.php on line 17
```

The file is definitely there.

Comment: Just above `if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 100000)` could you do a `var_dump` on `$_FILES` and paste the results?

Comment: Make sure the `upload` folder exists and has proper write permissions. As it stands, it seems that you're trying to upload to a non-existant folder. You may want to replace `upload` with `ubergallery/multiple_image_upload` or `multiple_image_upload`

Comment: Thanks for the answer Fred-ii. It looks like the "uploads" folder is set to "read-only" yet when uncheck this option, it sets itself back to "read-only" I am not sure what sets this to this option.

Comment: are you using any kind of source control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the appropriate permissions are assigned to the script and that there is a folder in the same location as the script titled `uploads`. CHMOD is what your looking for (Try to avoid 777, that's just lazy)

Also, is this a windows host? Though it doesn't matter you could try this:

```
$target_path = "uploads" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; //Declaring Path for uploaded images
```

Comment: Oxymoron, I have been trying to uncheck "read-only" for the folder "uploads" within Windows, yet it sets itself back again to "read-only". Do you have a suggestion? Thanks so far. I am also not sure how and from where the folder gets set to "read-only"?

Comment: Some source control systems will do this if a file is not properly checked out. Otherwise I would suggest using Sysinternals (Windows) to watch the folder and pinpoint what is setting this option.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. I have gotten it to work. When using this it works: `$target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/ubergallery/multiple_image_upload/uploads/";`

Comment: @ftxn Glad it all worked out for you, and I'm happy to see you pick up on the usage of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` :) Come back to SO anytime - we're happy to help when the question format is right!

Answer (score 1):

`No Such File or Directory` in this case most likely means that either the *source file* or the *destination directory* does not exist. If you're sure that the file exists, the `uploads/` directory is missing.

You may want to give the directory as an absolute path to avoid different scripts finding different directories.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have written a comment to Fred-ii.